# How does the compiler identify that the return types of overridden methods are incompatible in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

This might sound like a duplicate question but I am genuinely curious how the compiler identifies whether the overridden method and the overriding method have compatible types. As we know usually methods are identified using their signatures and the signatures only contain the method name and its parameters, thus while overloading it can easily figure out which method is to be picked and as a result, we cannot have two completely similar methods while overloading. But for overriding, we need both the methods two be identical. So how does the compiler identify whether the return types are compatible or not?

Edit. I am very aware that the method to be executed is picked based on the reference during runtime of the program, I am just curious on how the identification works for the compiler.

Comment: *"I am just curious on how the identification works for the compiler."* -  A good CS major will include an (optional) course on "compiler writing".  It is a final / honors year course ... and many students skip it because it has a reputation for being difficult.  There are also a few of (big) textbooks on this subject.  Anyway ... these will include lectures / chapters on types and compile time type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions how the compiler identifies an overriding method are

- method must have the same signature
- method must be at least as accessible as the parent method
- method must use covariant return type
- method must not declare any new or broader exception

as described in OCP II Study Guide.

Methods are overloaded if they have the same method name but a different argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a community which did not implement the Java compiler, all we can do is speculating, but nevertheless, speculating about this, as long as it's done objectively might turn out to be a good read.

So, my answer will focus on how methods *can* be validated as I do not know how it is actually being done by the compiler.

First of all, a very easy check is whether the number of parameters is the same. Also, the types of the parameters and the return type of the method need to be the same in order to have a method override at all.

I should mention that if in the child class you implement a new signature of the method, that's not a problem, that's perfectly legal.

So,

```
class A {
    int foo(long a) { return 0;}
}

class B extends A {
    int foo(long a) { return 0;}
}

class C extends A {
    int foo(double a) { return 0;}
}
```

is perfectly legal.

As a result, determining whether a method is an override of another method is important for Java to know how to apply inheritance-based logic, but you can easily implement methods with different declaration, yet, the same name.